# What kind of distribution might this be?

Tags: distributions, matlab, distribution-identification

I have ran a series of experiments on a theoretical system.  For a relatively small number of runs (~30) the data is normally distributed, but for longer runs (~200), a tail develops on the right... trying to think what other type of distribution this might be and whether there is a test in MATLAB?

[image: distn]

Comment: If the distributional shape changes with the number of runs, then no single distribution is likely to be a decent description of the data.

Comment: What do mean by "runs"? Are you independently repeating the same experiment, or is this a time series (your formulation "in the long run" seems to indicte in this direction).

Answer (score 2):

If the distribution shape changes over time, this means that observations are not distributed independently and identically (the main issue may be dependence, or non-identity, or both). Now if data are not independently and identically distributed, a histogram or kernel density estimator applied to the observations will *not* normally estimate "the" distribution, as there is no well defined single one. (Exception are data from a stationary process, but this runs counter to "shape changes over time"; at best, the process may at some point go into stationarity, in which case earlier observations should not be used for distribution estimation.)

So this question would require an analysis of what goes on over time, which cannot be seen from the histogram.

Answer (score -2):

Try Rayleigh distribution or $\chi^2$ distribution with, say, $n=4$. In Matlab, type `help\ raylpdf` and `help\ chi2pdf` for details.

Comment: This is so far from being Rayleigh or chi-squared that clearly you mean something more than you have written here.  Perhaps a *rescaled, recentered* version?  Unfortunately, histograms are poor tools for identifying continuous distributions.